# About staying in layover

Tags: luggage, layovers, mumbai, new-delhi

I will travel from Delhi to Canada. In way my flight there's a layover in Mumbai for 22 hrs. Can I stay in a hotel outside of the airport?

Second thing: will I receive my checked in luggage in Mumbai or will it stay in the sorting system in the airport?

Answer (score 1):

Since New Delhi and Mumbai are both in India, that portion of the flight will be **domestic**. Assume that most passengers of this domestic flight will also be leaving the airport.

You should ask the Airline to get a **reliable** answer about your luggage. The longer the layover, the less likly such a transfer of luggage will take place. It also depends on how the whole trip was booked. If you booked both flights separately, assume that you **must** pick up your bags in Mumbai.